# How do I use .htaccess to redirect an aspx page to a php page?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I recently moved from a asp.net host to a PHP host. I am trying to setup 301 redirects of my old urls using .htaccess. Here is what I want to accomplish:

```
old url: http://www.vasanth.in/downloads/download.aspx?file=file.zip
new url: http://www.vasanth.in/downloads/download.php?f=file.zip
```

I tried the following:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /downloads/download.aspx\?file=(.*)$ http://www.vasanth.in/downloads/download.php\?f=$1
```

This does not seem to work? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mod_rewrite`, something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^file=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.aspx$ $1.php?f=%1
```